# setAutocommit(true) further explanations

Tags: java, jdbc, commit

I have come across [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) oracle java tutorial. As a beginner in the topic I cannot grasp why it's needed to set `con.setAutocommit(true);` at the end of the transaction.

Here is the oracle explanation:

> The statement con.setAutoCommit(true); enables auto-commit mode, which
> means that each statement is once again committed automatically when
> it is completed. Then, you are back to the default state where you do
> not have to call the method commit yourself. It is advisable to
> disable the auto-commit mode only during the transaction mode. This
> way, you avoid holding database locks for multiple statements, which
> increases the likelihood of conflicts with other users.

Could you explain it in other words? especially this bit:

> This way, you avoid holding database locks for multiple statements,
> which increases the likelihood of conflicts with other users.

What do they mean with "holding database locks for multiple statements"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand Oracle's advice.  One can configure the connection to have autocommit off by default too, and then this advice tells you to turn it back on.  Wouldn't it be better to just restore the autocommit state at the end of the transaction?  In any case, I use transactions for all operations that modify the database, even if there is only one INSERT or UPDATE.  I have to remember less that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database has to perform row-level or table-level locking (based on your database-engine in MySQL) to handle transactions. If you keep the `auto-commit` mode `off` and keep executing statements, these locks won't be released until you commit the transactions. Based on the type, other transactions won't be able to update the row/table that is currently locked. `setAutocommit(true)` basically commits the current transaction, releases the locks currently held, and enables `auto-commit`, That is, until further required, each individual statement is executed and commited.

row-level locks protect the individual rows that take part in the transaction (InnoDB). Table-level locks prevent concurrent access to the entire table (MyIsam).

Comment: Ok I see. However Should not closing the connection and the statement  free the lock??

Comment: It is dependent on the driver in use. As mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()). It says that It is strongly recommended that an application explicitly commits or rolls back an active transaction prior to calling the close method. If the close method is called and there is an active transaction, the results are implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

When one transaction updates a row in the database others transaction cannot alter this row until the first one finishes (commits or rollbacks), therefore if you do not need transactions  it is advisable to set `con.setAutocommit(true)`.

Comment: Ok I see. However Should not closing the connection and the statement  free the lock?

Comment: Sure, closing the connection releases all the locks related to transactions.

Answer (score 1):

With most modern database systems you can batch together a series of SQL statements.  Typically the ones you care about are inserts as these will block out a portion of the space on disk that is being written to.  In JDBC this is akin to [Statement.addBatch(sql)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29).  Now where this becomes problematic is when you try to implement pessimistic or optimistic locks on tuples in the database.  So if you have a series of long running transactions that execute multiple batches you can find yourself in a situation where all reads get rejected because of these exclusive locks.  I believe in Oracle there is no such thing as the dirty read so this can potentially be mitigated.  But imagine the scenario where you are running a job that attempts to delete a record while I am updating it, this is the type of conflict that they are referring to.

With auto-commit on, each part of the batch is saved before moving on to the next unit of work.  This is what you see when trying to persist millions of records and it slows down considerably.  Because the system is ensuring consistency with each insert statement.  There is a quick way to get around this in Oracle (if you are using oracle) is to use the oracle.sql package and look at the `ARRAY` class.

Comment: Ok I see. However Should not closing the connection and the statement  free the lock?

Comment: @Rollerball there is no guarantee, it is purely dependent on when the database says it is done

Answer (score 1):

Most databases will `autoCommit` by default. That means that as soon as you execute a statement the results will immediately appear in the database and everyone else using the database will immediately see them.

There are times, however, when you need to perform a number of changes on the database which must all be done at once and if one fails you want to back out of all of them.

Say you have a cars database and you come across a new car from a new manufacturer. Here you may wish to create the manufacturer entry in your database **and** the new car record and make sure they both appear at once for other users. Otherwise there may be a confusing moment in your database where one exists without the other.

To achieve this you switch `autoCommit` **off**, execute the statements, commit them and then set `autoCommit` back on. This last switch on of `autoCommit` is probably what you are seeing.

Comment: Ok I see. However Should not closing the connection and the statement  free the lock?

Comment: *Should* - probably - but it is always better to be sure. Besides, connections are made to be re-used so you don't want to rely on the connection being closed to commit the transaction.